# Finding largest and smallest numbers within a file using Java

Tags: java, file

As part of this problem I needed to find:

- the amount of numbers (count)
- the sum of the numbers (sum)
- the average of the numbers (average)
- which numbers are even (evens)
- which numbers are odd (odds)

the last two things I need to find are the largest and smallest values.

My teacher wrote the base code already:

```
Scanner infile = new Scanner ( new FileReader(args[0]) );
int count=0,sum=0, largest=Integer.MIN_VALUE,smallest=Integer.MAX_VALUE, evens=0, odds=0;
double average=0.0;

while (infile.hasNext())
```

I've written the code for the listed variables within the while loop but I can't figure out what to do about the largest and smallest value.

I have tried doing this within the while loops:

```
if (count > largest)
   largest = count;

if (count < smallest)
   smallest = count;
```

The idea being that while the while loop iterates it will compare the number it passes against the largest value and it will match the largest one it finds in the count against largest and if the number it find is larger than largest, that becomes the new largest.  Same idea for smallest.

It is not working though.  What should I do?

I'm not sure if you guys need this but this is the code I wrote for the count within the while loop:

```
count += 1;
```

What should I do?

EDIT/ADD ON:
I figured you guys should see everything else I've actually done within the while loops:

```
while (infile.hasNext())
    {
        count += 1;
        sum += infile.nextInt();
        average = sum/count;
        if (sum%2 != 0)
            odds++;
        else
            evens++;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you comparing a count? You need to get the number from infile. Ex. `int currNum = infile.nextInt();` `if (currNum > largest)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java help: How to find largest number in scanned in file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689117/java-help-how-to-find-largest-number-in-scanned-in-file)

Comment: @Pith when I asked that question I got zero help. Please don't derail this one, as I'm actually getting constructive help.

Comment: It is not derailment, it is discouraging poor content.

Comment: @JasonMArcher no, you're discouraging new programmers.  It's unhelpful, uninspiring, and rude to those who simply wish to become better programmers.

Comment: There is certain behavior that makes a question unanswerable.  There is also certain behavior that is frowned upon because giving into it leads to no learning on the part of the questioner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is not tested, but it should do what you request.

```
 int count = 0, min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE,
       sum = 0, even = 0, odd = 0;
 while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    if (number < min)
        min = number;
    if (number > max)
        max = number;
    if (number % 2 == 0)
        even++;
    else
        odd++;
    sum+= number;
    count++;
 }
 double average = sum * 1.0 / count;
```

Comment: thanks you so much! thanks for not derailing it like stackoverflow is known to do with inexperienced programmers

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to do something like,

```
int count = 0, sum = 0, largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE, smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE, 
    evens = 0, odds = 0;
double average = 0.0;

while (infile.hasNext()) {
  if (infile.hasNextInt()) {
    int value = infile.nextInt();
    count++;
    sum += value;
    if (value > largest) {
      largest = value;
    }
    if (value < smallest) {
      smallest = value;
    }
    if (value % 2 == 0) {
      evens++;
    } else {
      odds++;
    }
  } else {
    infile.next();
  }
}
average = ((double) sum) / count;
System.out.printf("smallest = %d, largest = %d, average = %f, "
        + "sum = %d, count = %d, evens = %d, odds = %d%n",
        smallest, largest, average, sum, count,
        evens, odds);
```

Which I tested with a file containing

```
50 3 21 57 10 20
```

And I received the expected (formatted here) output of

```
smallest = 3, largest = 57, average = 26.833333, sum = 161, count = 6, evens = 3, 
odds = 3
```

Comment: you both were right be he answered it first! thanks you both so much for your help

Comment: thanks you so much! thanks for not derailing it like stackoverflow is known to do with inexperienced programmers